# C# Regex find last character of line

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

What I'm trying to achieve is show count of lines starting with/ending with `needle` character.

My code looks like that

```
case "Starting with":
    count = File.ReadLines(openFileDialog1.FileName)
                .Count(line => Regex.IsMatch(line, "^" + needle + ".*$"));
    break;
case "Ending with":
    count = File.ReadLines(openFileDialog1.FileName)
                .Count(line => Regex.IsMatch(line, "^.*" + needle + ".*$"));
    break;
```

Starting with finds right count, but ending with doesn't. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why would you use a regular expression for this? Just use `string.EndsWith` (and `string.StartsWith`), unless `needle` is *actually* a regular expression. (You mention it as a "character" in your question... if it's a user-entered character, you could end up with some unexpected results if the user enters "." for example.)

EDIT: Assuming you've got `needle` as a `string` (e.g. from `textBox.Text`)

```
case "Starting with":
    count = File.ReadLines(openFileDialog1.FileName)
                .Count(line => line.StartsWith(needle))
    break;
case "Ending with":
    count = File.ReadLines(openFileDialog1.FileName)
                .Count(line => line.EndsWith(needle))
    break;
```

(Note that you can extract the common functionality here if you want, by just assigning the predicate to a variable and then calling `ReadLines` and `Count` in a single place.)

Comment: can you give me an example with my code? How can I implement .EndsWith to my code?

Comment: @epic_syntax: Well how about you give us more information about what `needle` is to start with? You haven't really given us enough context here. Sample data and expected output would be really helpful. Then you can tell us why you're finding it hard to call `string.EndsWith`, and I can help you more.

Comment: Needle is 1 symbol entered by user. It's string. For ex, if txt file looks like "blabla<newline>blabla<newline>bbbbbb" and user enters `a` triest to find count of lines ending with a, then it must show, 2

Comment: Switch, is for combobox - searching type. User selects to search whether at the ends of the line or at the startings

Comment: @epic_syntax: So it's *just* a single character? And you actually want it to be treated literally, *not* as part of a regular expression?

Comment: Thx sir, thx very much. It's great pleasure for me to talk to StackKing

Answer (score 1):

Remove the .* at the end of the pattern:

```
Regex.IsMatch(line, "^.*" + needle + "$"));
```

Comment: Well the .* certainly shouldn't be there after `needle`, as currently your "Ending with" matches any line _containing_ `needle` instead of only _ending with_ it. Given `needle` is a character provided by the user though you may want to consider Skeet's answer though instead of using regular expressions.